# Add 1 to diagonal elements of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a list of lists of numbers, for example:

```
{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}
```

The length of the list is the same length of each sublist. What I want to achieve is to add plus 1 to the diagonal elements without using `For`. Given the list above as an input, I need a result like this:

```
{{2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why not `list + IdentityMatrix@Length@list`?

Comment: It works great, thank you!

Comment: @Simon, looks like an answer to me. ;)

Comment: Next time if you [cross-post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1187440), please link the two posts together.

Comment: @SimonRochester Hei man,that is a good answerr. :)

Answer (score 13):

By popular demand:

```
list + IdentityMatrix@Length@list
```

I'm a big fan of `IdentityMatrix` -- I try to use it whenever possible.

Answer (score 4):

Using some *undocumented* functionality,

```
m = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}};
diag = ConstantArray[1, Length[m]];

LinearAlgebra`AddVectorToMatrixDiagonal[m, diag]
   {{2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}}
```

For 11.2, use `` LinearAlgebra`Private`AddVectorToMatrixDiagonal[] `` instead.

Comment: why this dosn't work anymore!?

Comment: In which version?

Comment: 10.4.1.
Check my new Question please!

Answer (score 3):

I am hoping that Table is ok with you !

```
In[1]:= list = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}

Table[list[[i, i]] = list[[i, i]] + 1, {i, 1, Length[list]}];

In[3]:= list

Out[3]= {{2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}}
```

Comment: `Table[list[[i, i]]++, {i, 1, Length[list]}];` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
m = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}};
mnew = ReplacePart[m, {i_, i_} :> m[[i, i]] + 1]
```